# How to obtain variable value outside of function to use with OFFSET

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax

I'm trying to use `OFFSET` in my mySQL query to return new rows of values every time the user scrolls to a certain point on the page. I want to get the original data as well as the future data that is returned when the user scrolls in the same AJAX call because the way I have been doing it up to this point included two different functions, one for getting the original data that was loaded in and one for getting the new data, which is harder to maintain. For example, if I was getting comments, I would use two functions:

```
function getComments() {

    $.ajax({}); //ajax call to load first five comments

    $(".threads").scroll(function() {

            if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).height() >= $(this).prop('scrollHeight') - 1) {

                getMoreComments(); //call function that loads more comments using "OFFSET" in sql query

            }
        });
    }
```

The only difference between my `getComments()` function and my `getMoreComments()` was that the AJAX call went to separate PHP pages which had the same code, except the `getMoreComments()` PHP page contained an `OFFSET` in the SQL query. Wanting to combine these functions, I tried using `OFFSET` in one AJAX function and set a variable that contained the offset value I wanted, but ran into a problem: the variable outside of the function wasn't giving me its value inside the function. My function, `getMyForumLikes()`, looks like this (shortened for brevity):

```
    var getMyForumLikesOffset = 0;

    function getMyForumLikes() {

        $.ajax({
            url: 'includes/feed/getMyForumLikes.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {idUsers: idUsers, offset: getMyForumLikesOffset},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                data.forEach(function(item) {
                    console.log(item);

                    //do stuff with returned data here

                });

            }
        });

    }

    $(".threads").scroll(function() { //call function again, increasing variable getMyForumLikesOffset to get new returned rows using OFFSET when user scrolls to bottom of div.

        if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).height() >= $(this).prop('scrollHeight') - 1) {

            getMyForumLikes();
            getMyForumLikesOffset = getMyForumLikesOffset + 5;

        }

    });
```

I included the scroll function to run the function again to obtain more rows when the user scrolls down to the bottom of the div. The `getMyForumLikes.php` page looks like this (shortened for brevity):

```
<?php

include '../dbh.inc.php';

$idUsers = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['idUsers']);
$offset = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['offset']);

$q = "SELECT forumvotes.vote_id, forumvotes.idUsers AS voterId, forums.forum_id, forums.forum_title, forums.idUsers AS forumCreatorId, forums.seen, users.uidUsers, profileimages.image FROM forumvotes JOIN forums JOIN users JOIN profileimages ON profileimages.idUsers = users.idUsers AND forumvotes.forum_id = forums.forum_id AND forumvotes.idUsers = users.idUsers WHERE forums.idUsers = '$idUsers' AND forumvotes.idUsers != '$idUsers' ORDER BY forumvotes.vote_id DESC LIMIT 5 OFFSET $offset";
$r = mysqli_query($conn, $q);

//do stuff with returned rows here
```

The problem that occurs is when the ajax call executes, I get an error saying that `$offset` is not defined. I believe this is because of the scope of the variable as it is outside the function and I am trying to call it inside the function, so it doesn't work. My question is this: how can I obtain the value of the `getMyForumLikesOffset` variable within the function to get the new rows I want? Is this possible, or do I have to use two functions to get new offset values? Let me know if this is confusing in any way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, you are able to use variables outside of the function scope just fine.

```js
var a = 4;
(function () {
  console.log(a); // 4
}());
```

The real issue is that PHP is not understanding your JSON. To get PHP to parse your JSON use `json_decode`.

```php
print_r(json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')));
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused about this - when I set `var a = 4` and call it using the jQuery function written as you did (`$(function() { console.log(a); });`), it logs "4". However, when I create a javascript function like `function nameHere() { console.log(a) }` and call it using `nameHere()`, it logs a value of "undefined". Do you know why this is?

Comment: I just figured something out. I think it has to do with where I'm calling the function. If I call it after the written function, it seems to log correctly, but not when I do it before.

Comment: Ah gotcha. Though please fix the `$_POST`. `$_POST` is for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` but I see you are using JSON in `dataType`. You need `json_decode` if you are using JSON.

Comment: Are you saying I should use `json_decode` inside the `$idUsers` and other variables on the PHP page, like so? `$idUsers = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, json_decode($_POST['idUsers']));`

Comment: Sorry, I got confused, I thought at the time I thought that `dataType` was the Content-Type of the request, but no, it's actually the setting for the server response type. You'd do `json_decode` if you sending pure JSON string with `contentType ` or something, but that's not what you're doing. Carry on

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the help.